# MacBook updated to OS X Yosemite version 10.10 and experiencing problems with hard drive & iPhoto

Tags: macos, hard-drive, photos.app

I updated my MacBook to OS X Yosemite version 10.10. Everything seems to be fine... apart from:

1. My WD hard drive won't open now - it appears on screen, allows me to enter the password to unlock and then give me this message:

NTFS-3G could not mount /dev/disk2s1
at /Volumes/My Passport because the following problem occurred:

/Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/fusefs.kext failed to load - (libkern/kext) link error; check the system/kernel logs for errors or try kextutil(8).
the MacFUSE file system is not available (71)

2. My iPhoto's has a 'no entry' symbol over it and it won't let me access it... does this mean I have lost all of my photos!?!?

Any advice on these 2 things would be much appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned kexts are no longer allowed to run by default in Yosemite.

Solutions include...

- upgrade to one of the [paid] NTFS apps that still work - [Tuxera](http://www.tuxera.com/ntfs/tuxera-ntfs-for-mac-for-os-x-yosemite/) or [Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/)
  *Requires you to fully uninstall NTFS-3G first*
- disable the Mac's kext policy - easiest way might be to install [TRIM Enabler](http://www.cindori.org/trim-enabler-and-yosemite/), which will do it for you [though I don't know if it would install with no SSD present, never tested]
- or the long way - *[this is untested, method from cindori, the makers of TRIM Enabler - it might only be for that app]*
  Boot your Mac in Recovery Mode by holding  <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>   <kbd>R</kbd>   during boot
  Open the Terminal from the menu bar
  Run these commands, replacing YourDisk with the name of your Mac disk

  - `rm -rf /Volumes/YourDisk/System/Library/Extensions/IOAHCIFamily.kext`
  - `cp -r /System/Library/Extensions/IOAHCIFamily.kext /Volumes/YourDisk/System/Library/Extensions/IOAHCIFamily.kext`
  - `touch /Volumes/YourDisk/System/Library/Extensions`
  - `kextcache -u /Volumes/YourDisk`

  Wait until it finishes (can take up to 1 min)